# google gdata api in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gdata-api

i am in process of creating a image catlogue for a client, i was thinking that upload the relevent images to picasa and make it as private, then using gdata fetch the album name of the particular picasa user , after choosing it show all the images of the album in thumbnails in site. i am planning todo with asp.net and gdata , i am struck with the authentication process, i dont want the client to create a gmail id for each of his customer to view the catlog images, is there any possible way to show all the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tag the photos with user names, then you can store them all in one album under one Gmail account, and retrieve the correct subset of photos based on the associated tags.

You could also use the facial recognition feature to make the tagging process easier for yourself, if there are people in the photos.

Comment: hi RedFilter, thanks for the post, if i understand correctly, that i should tag the photo like this <username>-ring1,<username>-ring2 , correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That sounds right. But try it out, and flip them around depending on what the API gives you back.